# Upload Security Error (firefox only) : Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: javascript, php, firefox, cross-domain, magento-1.7

Upload Security Error (firefox only) : Magento 1.7.0.2

- upload image in add prodcut
- error (Upload Security Error) firefox only. in IE and Chrome Success
- english domain is Success. But my domain is thai domain (xn--22ckk2da5e8bbba8hqh6bwc.net) is error

Thank you for solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

****Solution : use extension "No Flash Image Uploader"

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/no-flash-image-uploader.html

- it for version 1.4
- but work in version 1.7.0.2 too.****